# Running Ableton Live on Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware

Does anyone know if it's possible to run Ableton Live on the RPi? Version 9 of Ableton requires 4GB of RAM so I guess not, but version 7 needs 512MB of RAM. I thought it would be possible to run that on a RPi running Windows 10 Core. Any ideas?

Comment: What is Ableton Live?  Do you have the source code?  If not is there a version compiled for ARM.  Windows 10 IOT is not the same as Windows 10.

Comment: It's a closed source music processing program https://www.ableton.com/. It appears it's possible to run it on Ubuntu with WINE. Not sure how RPi will like it though.

Comment: I believe wine is only usable on x86 (Intel machine code) machines.  An ARM has different machine code.

Comment: Ah, hadn't considered that. So I'm out of ideas on how to make this work on site.

Comment: Old laptops are probably your best bet for a cheap option. I used to run ProTools 7/8 on a 2009 Dell machine, and it did fine for simple tracking and mixing. I can't imagine it would cost much more than £50 for something similar on Ebay these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to run any version of Ableton. There are no packages available for ARM architecture CPUs. Windows IoT for the Pi isn't Windows as you know it - it can't run standard Windows applications and is intended more for embedded devices.

Even if it were possible to install Ableton, it would be a pretty miserable experience. The Pi's disk bandwidth wouldn't allow you to work with more than, being pretty optimistic, one or two tracks, and the CPU just isn't fast enough to process high quality audio effects at a reasonable pace.

Comment: Any updates since RPI4 is out? Are there still no ARM builds?